# How to upload a excel file in pythonanywhere server, I have uploaded python script, my python script reads the excel file and then it executes tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

I have uploaded a python script on PythonAnywhere server for free, I have a excel file in my computer, my python script reads the excel data and executes some tasks and email me, and I have written a excel file location in my python script. How should I add excel file to server, and should I axis that file from script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every directory in your Files pages has an upload button that you can use to upload a file to that directory.